# How to generate code for in-register named local values in LLVM IR?

Tags: code-generation, llvm

I am generating LLVM IR (.ll files) from a source language. This language doesn't have any mutable local variables and I don't use any `alloca`s yet, everything so far is in LLVM registers. It does have immutable local values, though. Currently, they work fine unless the initializer part is a constant or another identifier. For example:

```
def fun(a: Int, b: Int) = {
  val n = a + b
  n + 2
}
```

This compiles fine, because `a + b` compiles to the instruction `add i32 %a, %b` and instructions can be optionally assigned to local values, so the line becomes: `%n = add i32 %a, %b`.

On the other hand, I have trouble generating code for the following:

```
def fun() = {
  val n = 1
  n
}
```

I could generate `%n = bitcast i32 1 to i32` but bitcast doesn't work with all types and is not really intended for this. Well, I guess in LLVM there is really nothing specifically intended for this, otherwise I wouldn't have the question.

But is there a good solution without generating tons of different no-op instructions depending on the type of the value? bitcast will not work with tuples for example:

```
error: invalid cast opcode for cast from '{ i32, i32 }' to '{ i32, i32 }'
%n = bitcast {i32, i32} {i32 1, i32 2} to {i32, i32}
```

Then again, maybe because there are no 'copy' instructions in the IR, I shouldn't be trying to do this and should be replacing %n with the value everywhere it is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

1. Generate the code using alloca's, load and stores (check e.g. clang's or llvm-gcc's output at -O0) and then use -mem2reg optimization pass to raise all this stuff to LLVM registers
2. Use 1 instead of %n everywhere.